# read comma as a new line through xslt

Tags: 2013, core-service, xslt, xslt-mediator

`

```
<Telephone>1234 64 79 31 6,345664 01 04 23, 55551 04 24</Telephone>
```

`
There is a tridion component, which has telephone number as a simple text field.multiple numbers are given in that field separated by a comma.But on application i want them to come in a new line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845660/xsl-how-to-split-strings

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tridion="http://www.xyz.com/tridion/schemas">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="tridion:Office/tridion:Telephone/text()" name="split">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
        <xsl:if test="not($pText=.)">
            <br />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText,','),',')"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="split">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>         

<xsl:template match="office" >
    <h5 id="{@id}">
        <a href="#" property="v:name">
            <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
        </a>
    </h5>
    <div xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#" typeof="v:Organization">
        <div>
            <p>
                <div class="addressDetails">

                    <xsl:if test="telephone/text()">
                        <div class="moreDetails">
                            <p>
                                <span>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="utils:Text('Telephone')"/>
                                </span>
                            </p>
                            <p>

                                <span class="normalfont" property="v:tel">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="telephone/text()"/> 

                                </span>
                            </p>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <xsl:comment></xsl:comment>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </xsl:if>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Stanislav, Thanks for your time, but what should be placed in "text()" and "pText"

Comment: text() should be replaced with path to your node in your xml file, like "/Office/Telephone/text()" - that means that all text inside all <telephone> nodes inside all <Office> will be replaced, pText is just a name of parameter in xslt - you can left it as is.

Comment: I have updated the xslt. The problem was in namespaces.

Comment: I used following website to check: http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php . And I do not see any problems with your xml and mine xslt. Is there anything else in your xml or in your resulted xslt?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. I updated my xslt with some more details.and the place where i am inserting the given xslt.

Comment: With your xslt I have a problem that you open <div> tag twice, but close only once. When I added </div> before </xsl:if> it worked for me. Please make sure that you have same number of closing tags for all opened ones.

Comment: You can add my template before yours. I have updated mine xslt with yours additions. Will this work for you?